# jqgrid search popup allows all filters to be removed!

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying out very simple search popup on the JqGrid. Please see the code below. There are few issues:

- The popup comes up with AND/OR and [+] controls at the very top. See screenshot below: (from FF 4)[image]
- You can click on [-] button to remove the very first (and only) filter row. It shouldn't be allowed. First filter row should never be allowed to be removed.
- Code:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html>
  <head>
  <title>JQGRID Test</title>      
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          createGrid();
      });
      function createGrid() {
          $("#jqgrid-table").jqGrid({
              colNames:['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age', 'IQ', 'Type'],
              colModel:[
                  {name:'firstName',index:'firstName', width:100},
                  {name:'lastName',index:'lastName', width:100},
                  {name:'age', index:'age', width:50},
                  {name:'iq', index:'iq', width:50, stype:'select', searchoptions: {dataUrl:'/api/domains/putcalldomain'}},
                  {name:'type', index:'type', width: 56}
              ],
              width: 800,
              datatype:'local',                   
              pager: '#pager2',
              viewrecords: true,
              caption:"JSON Example"
          });
          var searchOptions = {
              caption: 'Filter...',
              multipleSearch:true,
              closeAfterSearch:true,
              closeAfterReset:true,
              Find: 'Filter'
          };                
          jQuery("#jqgrid-table").jqGrid('navGrid',
                                  '#pager2', 
                                  {search:true, edit:false, add:false, del:false, refresh:false}, 
                                  null, null, null, searchOptions
                                  );
          var data = getData();
          for(var i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
              var r = data[i];
              jQuery("#jqgrid-table").addRowData(r.id, r);
          }
      }
      function getData() {
          return [
                 {id:1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'XXX',  age:'30',  iq:'200', type: 'Nice'},
                 {id:2, firstName: 'Ashley', lastName:'YYY', age:'31', iq:'210', type:'Nicer'},
                 {id:3, firstName:'Smith', lastName:'ZZZ', age:'23', iq:'90', type:'Nicest'}
              ];
     }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='jqgrid-div'>
        <table id='jqgrid-table'></table>
       <div id="pager2"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to **overwrite** the internal `reDraw` method used by filtering (see [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116402/remove-search-operator-and-or-in-multiplesearch-jqgrid/6117193#6117193) for more description). To do this you should include in the `searchOptions` which you use the `beforeShowSearch`  event handler with the following implementation:

```
beforeShowSearch: function($form) {
    var searchDialog = $form[0],
        oldrReDraw = searchDialog.reDraw, // save the original reDraw method
        doWhatWeNeed = function() {
            $('input.delete-rule:first',searchDialog).unbind('click');

            // set fucus in the last input field
            setTimeout(function() {
               // set fucus in the last input field
               $('input[type="text"]:last',searchDialog).focus();
            }, 50);
        }
    searchDialog.reDraw = function() {
        oldrReDraw.call(searchDialog);    // call the original reDraw method
        doWhatWeNeed();
    }
    doWhatWeNeed();
}
```

You can see the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithAdvSearching2.htm).