# Remove search operator (AND/OR) in multiplesearch jqGrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I need to hide the operator in the search popup, but I cannot get it to work. 
I tried this, but both operators still appear:

```
jQuery("#grilla").navGrid("#paginador",
{del:false,add:false,edit:false},{},{},{},{
groupOps: [{ op: "OR", text: "any" }], multipleSearch:true});
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no option which can directly do what you need. Moreover if you would hide the ADD/OR operand from the searching dialog at the dialog initialization (for example inside of [beforeShowSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options) event handler) with `$('select.opsel').hide()` the select element will be hidden **only at the beginning**. After the user click on any button the dialog contain will be repaint without calling of any event handler and the select element will be again visible.

So I suggest to solve the problem with overwriting the method [reDraw](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.0.0/js/grid.filter.js#L167) of the filter dialog. The code which do this can look like

```
jQuery("#grilla").jqGrid("navGrid","#paginador",
    {del: false, add: false, edit: false}, {}, {}, {},
    {
        multipleSearch: true,
        beforeShowSearch: function($form) {
            var searchDialog = $form[0],
                oldrReDraw = searchDialog.reDraw, // save the original reDraw method
                doWhatWeNeed = function () {
                    // hide the AND/OR operation selection
                    $('select.opsel', searchDialog).hide();

                    setTimeout(function () {
                       // set fucus in the last input field
                       $('input[type="text"]:last', searchDialog).focus();
                    }, 50);
                }
            searchDialog.reDraw = function () {
                oldrReDraw.call(searchDialog);    // call the original reDraw method
                doWhatWeNeed();
            }
            doWhatWeNeed();
        }
    }
);
```

You can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithAdvSearching1.htm) that the way really works.

**UPDATED**: After writing of the answer I posted some suggestions to trirand to improve jqGrid. Now jqGrid has many features which simplify the above work. For example there are exist `afterRedraw` callback which can be directly used. So the code from the answer will look like

```
grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager",
    {add: false, edit: false, del: false}, {}, {}, {},
    {
        multipleSearch: true,
        afterRedraw: function (p) {
            var $form = $(this);
            $form.find("select.opsel").hide();
            setTimeout(function () {
               // set fucus in the last input field
               $form.find('input[type="text"]:last').focus();
            }, 50);
            $form.find("input.add-rule,input.delete-rule").button();
        }
    }
);
```

See the modified demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithAdvSearching1_.htm):

[image]

I added one more line in the code of `afterRedraw`

```
$form.find("input.add-rule,input.delete-rule").button();
```

only to improve the look of buttons in the Searching Dialog. I suggested to make such settings default in jqGrid, but this was not accepted by trirand. In any way everyone who includes jQuery UI can add such line in `afterRedraw` to make the buttons flat.

Comment: Doesn't work for 4.4.3 and I guess it doesn't work for >=4.4.0

Comment: @PavelKovalev: After writing of the answer I posted some suggestions to trirand. So the code have to be changed (simplified). See "**UPDATED**" part of my answer which I wrote for you.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me with 4.4.0.

Much simpler seems to be to hook the afterRedraw event and remove the opsel select element:

```
jQuery("#grilla")jqGrid(
    "navGrid","#paginador", {del:false,add:false,edit:false},{},{},{},
    {
        multipleSearch:true,
        afterRedraw: function($p) { 
            $("select.opsel").remove(); 
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

see here !

```
 //own add edit del search 
        jQuery("#gridTable3").jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridPager3',
        {
        //options
        },
        {
            // edit options
            height: 250,
            reloadAfterSubmit: false,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            afterSubmit: function(r, data) {
                var messageString = r.responseText;
                var mesObj = eval('(' + messageString + ')');
                return [mesObj.state, mesObj.message];
            }
        },
        {
            // add options
            height: 250,
            reloadAfterSubmit: false,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            afterSubmit: function(r, data) {
                var messageString = r.responseText;
                var mesObj = eval('(' + messageString + ')');
                return [mesObj.state, mesObj.message];
            }
        },
         {
             // del options
             reloadAfterSubmit: false,
             closeAfterDel: true,
             afterSubmit: function(r, data) {
                 var messageString = r.responseText;
                 var mesObj = eval('(' + messageString + ')');
                 return [mesObj.state, mesObj.message];
             }
         },
        {
            // search options
            multipleSearch: true,//more search  write there,don't pop
            afterSubmit: function(r, data) {
                var messageString = r.responseText;
                var mesObj = eval('(' + messageString + ')');
                return [mesObj.state, mesObj.message];
            }
        });
```